# Nautilus 18.04/20.04, hide specific drives in Other Locations

Tags: nautilus

So, I have lots of drives in zfs. In Nautilus, under Other Locations -> On This Computer all of them show up, say 30 of them. Essentially, if I have a zfs pool named Internal, then, I see 30 Internal "drives", and if you click on them, they try and mount which they can't of course. Apparently, zfs has a small unused near as I can tell partition at the end of drives. So, they show as /dev/sda9, /dev/sdb9, etc. I'd like to hide all those in Nautilus so I can see quicker and easier non ZFS drives, and, Networks. Is there any way to hide them? I looked in dconf, and, settings for Nautilus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nautilus does not display volumes in the location pane if those volumes have to be mounted elsewhere than in `/media`
You can 'hide' a partition by specifying a mountpoint elsewhere than in `/media` in the `fstab` file. Of course, lets play with mount option to not mount those volume at boot.

The lines in fstab should look like this :

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
  /dev/sdXY      /mnt/uniq       zfs     noauto          0       0
# mountpoint should be uniq
# noauto, parition will not be mounted at startutp, not mouted with mount -a
# fsck option 0 & 0 But why not use recommended settings for zfs
```

Example with `/dev/sda9`

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/hidesda9
echo "/dev/sda9 /mnt/hidesda9 zfs noauto 0 0" | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
sudo mount -a
```